# which variable is being accessed, local or class level?

Tags: java, lambda, scope

Consider the following code given in [Lambda Expressions](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/lambdaexpressions.html) :

```
import java.util.function.Consumer;

public class LambdaScopeTest {

    public int x = 0;

    class FirstLevel {

        public int x = 1;

        void methodInFirstLevel(int x) {

            // The following statement causes the compiler to generate
            // the error "local variables referenced from a lambda expression
            // must be final or effectively final" in statement A:
            //
            // x = 99;

            Consumer<Integer> myConsumer = (y) -> 
            {
                System.out.println("x = " + x); // Statement A
                System.out.println("y = " + y);
                System.out.println("this.x = " + this.x);
                System.out.println("LambdaScopeTest.this.x = " +
                    LambdaScopeTest.this.x);
            };

            myConsumer.accept(x);

        }
    }

    public static void main(String... args) {
        LambdaScopeTest st = new LambdaScopeTest();
        LambdaScopeTest.FirstLevel fl = st.new FirstLevel();
        fl.methodInFirstLevel(23);
    }
}
```

In the JavaDocs it is written that :

> suppose that you add the following assignment statement immediately
>   after the `methodInFirstLevel` definition statement:
>
> ```
>  void methodInFirstLevel(int x) {
>      x = 99;
>      // ... }
> ```
>
> Because of this assignment statement, the variable `FirstLevel.x` is not effectively final anymore. As a result, the Java
>   compiler generates an error message similar to "local variables
>   referenced from a lambda expression must be final or effectively
>   final" where the lambda expression myConsumer tries to access the
>   `FirstLevel.x` variable:
>
> `System.out.println("x = " + x);`

I'm unable to understand that at `System.out.println("x = " + x)` (statement A) how FirstLevel.x will be accessed? Shouldn't it be the `x` passed in the method `methodInFirstLevel(int x)`?

Comment: I think it means that the lambda expression is failing to access the `x` argument in `methodInFirstLevel(int x)` because it is not effectively final. It may be confusingly (or indeed wrongly) worded.

Comment: Compiler doesn't know, what you are doing in `myConsumer.accept(x);`, so it assumes, that `x` may be changed in this method, and if it is it can not be final. That's why you are getting error.

Comment: @TEXHIK, since Java is pass-by-value, `myConsumer` cannot change `x`. This is not the issue.

Comment: This appears to be an error in the tutorial. It would make much more sense it it said “Because of this assignment statement, the parameter `x` is not effectively final anymore. ”

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This appears to be an error in the tutorial. I believe the paragraph ought to read:

> Because of this assignment statement, the parameter `x` is not
>   effectively final anymore. As a result, the Java compiler generates an
>   error message similar to "local variables referenced from a lambda
>   expression must be final or effectively final" where the lambda
>   expression myConsumer tries to access the `x` parameter:
>
> ```
> System.out.println("x = " + x);
> ```

I rest my argument on two observations: the quoted error message says “local variables”, which might include parameters, but not fields. The quoted print statement prints 23, which is the value of the parameter, not the value of the `FirstLevel.x`.

Answer (score 0):

Always: if you have any local variable in a method then Java will first prefer local variable then class reason is that local variables have very limited scope and class variable can be access in all methods of the class

Answer (score 0):

Java always uses the innermost variable with the given name.

That results in this hierarchy (descending order):

- Method local variable
- Class variable/field
- Parent class variable/field
- Wrapping class variable/field

Unless you explicitly qualify it with `this.var` or `Class.var`.